# LCD write update issue

Tags: c, lcd, arduino-uno

I am using arduino Uno and 16X2 lCD for programming. I have almost written code which seems working. I am facing small problem while updating LCD values.I cant paste my full code, just pasting part of it.It just menu selection and Editing option. i am pasting part by part.

This How called in Loop

```
void loop()
{
    LCD_Display();
    CHK_Key();
    wdt_reset();
    Track_loop();
    //Serial.println("..........................");
}
```

LCD Display program called below

```
void LCD_Display()
{
    Display_counter1=Display_counter1+1;

    if(Update_Screen==1)
    {
        lcdClear();
        switch(cur_disp_screen_type1)
        {
            case DATE_TIME:digitalClockDisplay();break;
            case COORDINATE:Display_coordinate();break;
            case WIND_SPEED: Display_Wind();break;
            case SOLAR_ANGLE:Display_angle();break;
            case SET_PARAMETER:Set_Parameter();break;
            case GET_PASSWORD:GetEditPassword(Edit_password,4);Blink_Password(current_Password);break;
            case EDIT_MODE:Edit_parameter();break;
            case EDIT_DATE_TIME:ClockEditDisplay(edit_date_time,6); Blink_LCD(cur_edit_item);break;
            case EDIT_TRACK_TIME:Track_Edit_Display(edit_track_time,2);Blink_Track(cur_edit_time_item);break;
            case EDIT_COORDINATE:Edit_Coordinate_Display(edit_cordinate,4);Blink_Coordinate(cur_coordinate_item);break;
            case EDIT_LIMIT:Edit_Limit_Display(edit_limits,4); Blink_Limit(cur_edit_limit);break;
        }
        Update_Screen=0;
        if( cur_disp_screen_type1>DISPLAY_COUNT_MAX)
        {
            cur_disp_screen_type1= DATE_TIME;
        }
    }
    if(Display_counter1>=6)
    {
        Display_counter1=0;Update_Screen=1;
    }
}
```

I can read the values properly . So problem while Editing. So Here is part of editing option.

```
void GetEditPassword(int password_data[],int size)
{
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.write("ENTER PASSWORD  ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(password_data[0]);
    lcd.print(password_data[1]);
    lcd.print(password_data[2]);
    lcd.print(password_data[3]);
    lcd.print("              ");
}
```

Here i have doubt i am setting cursor 0,0 and 0,1 . so every time function called i am assuming these function being updated so because of which i can see letters behind while editing. My question is How to ovecome this problem.

```
void Blink_Password(int Password_pos)
{ 
    int term1;
    int term2;
    lcd.blink();
    delay(40);
    switch(Password_pos)
    {
    case PASSWORD_ITEM1:  lcd.print(password1);Update_Screen=1; 
                          goto PASSWORD;
                          break;

    case PASSWORD_ITEM2:lcd.print(password2);Update_Screen=1; 
                             goto PASSWORD;
                          break;

    case PASSWORD_ITEM3:lcd.print(password3);Update_Screen=1; 
                          goto PASSWORD;
                          break;


    case PASSWORD_ITEM4:lcd.print(password4);Update_Screen=1; 
                           goto PASSWORD;
                          break;                      
    }
PASSWORD:   lcd.setCursor(Blink_password_pos[Password_pos][0],Blink_password_pos[Password_pos][1]);
    lcd.noCursor();//timedBeep(shortBeep,1);
    delay(40);
}
```